# Unable to understand lists in dart consider the example provided

Tags: list, algorithm, flutter, dart

I am developing an app in flutter. For which I am using lists of map but there something that I am unable to undertand. Consider the following cases:

- **SCENARIO 1**

  ```
  void main() {
    List<Map<String,String>> _reminders = [];
    Map<String , String> _tempMap = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      _tempMap.clear();
      _tempMap.putIfAbsent('M' , () => 'm ' + i.toString());
      _tempMap.putIfAbsent('D' , () => 'd : ' + i.toString());

      _reminders.add(_tempMap);
      // or _reminders.insert(i, _tempMap);
    }
    print(_reminders.toString());
    return;
  }
  ```

to which the result is as follows

```
[{M: m 4, D: d : 4}, {M: m 4, D: d : 4}, {M: m 4, D: d : 4}, {M: m 4, D: d : 4}, {M: m 4, D: d : 4}]
```

- **SCENARIO 2**

  ```
  void main() {
    List<Map<String,String>> _reminders = [];


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      Map<String , String> _tempMap = {};
      _tempMap.putIfAbsent('M' , () => 'm ' + i.toString());
      _tempMap.putIfAbsent('D' , () => 'd : ' + i.toString());

      _reminders.add(_tempMap);;
    }
    print(_reminders.toString());
    return;
  }
  ```

to which the result is as follows

```
[{M: m 0, D: d : 0}, {M: m 1, D: d : 1}, {M: m 2, D: d : 2}, {M: m 3, D: d : 3}, {M: m 4, D: d : 4}]
```

As far as I understand, these scenarios should give similar results. Also in my use case scenario 2 is the correct way as it gives me the result that I want. Please note the above examples have been changed to similify the question. The usage in my original code is much more complex.

Comment: In the first case you're referecing the same object, so you're basically pushing the same object over and over again in the list, while in the second case you're pushing a new object every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> From my understanding, both are different

The problem is with `_tempMap.clear();` in the **SCENARIO 1**. You have used the global variable for map object and when you apply clear inside the for loop all the previously  added entries will be cleared and map becomes empty.

*when i = 0 => {}  => clear() => all entries will be cleared => New item inserted.*

*when i = 1 => {"Item inserted in 0th iteration"}  => clear() => all entries will be cleared => New item inserted.*

So for every iteration map is cleared and holds only last iterated value. After for loop is completed it contains only the last iterated value(i=4) since we are clearing the global map variable every time when a new iteration starts.

**EDIT** :
You can print the map values inside the for loop and can check yourself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('\n $i => ${_tempMap} \n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart, like many other programming languages including java, stores objects as reference, and not contiguous memory blocks. In the first case, in all the iterations of the loop, you have added the same `Map` using the `_reminders.add(_tempMap)`. Your intuition that *"Everytime I add the `Map`, a copy is created of the current state of `Map` and that copy is appended to the list"* is incorrect.

Comment: Thankyou. Your answer makes sense. So everytime I do list.add(map). I still have a reference of the original map in the list. Meaning if I externally change the map after adding it to the list the data in the list will also change correct? Is there a way to actually store a copy of the oriinal data in the list and break the link between the oriinal map and the list? thanks